# Get the values from array with 2 differents inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate a dynamically array of inputs but I can't figure out how to do it, this is my html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentContactDesc" placeholder="Description">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="studentContactPhone" placeholder="Phone">
```

When the user clicks on a button the process add more inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentContactDesc" placeholder="Description">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="studentContactPhone" placeholder="Phone">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentContactDesc" placeholder="Description">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="studentContactPhone" placeholder="Phone">
```

Every time the user clicks on the button the process add the same two lines.

I'm reading the data with:

```
$(document).on('click','#saveRecord',function() {
    $("input[name=studentContactDesc]").each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $("input[name=studentContactPhone]").each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

This function reads all the description fields first, and then all the phone fields.

If there any way to read a description field with the phone and the other fields with the same order?

Comment: Will each student `contact description` always have its corresponding `Contact phone` ?

Comment: Right, in the description could input Home Phone and the number 123456789 in the other Mom cell and the number 123456789.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the function as below to simultaneously alert the `description` as well as the `phone` info.

```
   $(document).on('click','#saveRecord',function() {
    var contact = $("input[name=studentContactDesc]");
    var phone =  $("input[name=studentContactPhone]");
    for(var i=0;i<contact.length;i++){
        alert(contact[i].value);
        alert(phone[i].value);
     }
   });
```

Comment: ups, so simple! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each set of inputs in a div and iterate over the divs.
    
         `<div class='item'>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentContactDesc" placeholder="Description">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="studentContactPhone" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>`

```
<code>
$('.item').each(function(){
     var values = "";
     $(this).children('input').each(function() { 
         values += $(this).val() + " ";
    });
    alert(values);
 });
</code>
```